# How do I group by the outcome and severity header in xlsxwriter

Tags: pandas, xlsxwriter

can anybody help me categorize the header of outcome and severity to show the FAIL and HIGH  values highlighted in red at the top while the rest will be in descending order using xlsxwriter. I really can't understand how the structure works.

[image]

To an outcome of something like this. To order the FAIL first and afterwards the severity of HIGH.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide your desired output?

Comment: To something like this. To order the FAIL first and afterwards the severity of HIGH.

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Outcome':['Pass', 'Fail', 'Pass', 'Fail', 'Fail'], 'Severity':['High', 'Medium', 'Low', 'Medium', 'High']})

  Outcome Severity
0    Pass     High
1    Fail   Medium
2    Pass      Low
3    Fail   Medium
4    Fail     High
```

Doing:

```
# Make your columns custom ordered categoricals:
df.Outcome = pd.Categorical(df.Outcome, ordered=True, categories=['Fail', 'Pass'])
df.Severity = pd.Categorical(df.Severity, ordered=True, categories=['Low', 'Medium', 'High'])

# Sort, the sort will follow the category order, instead of Alphabetical.
df = df.sort_values(['Outcome', 'Severity'], ascending=[True, False], ignore_index=True)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  Outcome Severity
0    Fail     High
1    Fail   Medium
2    Fail   Medium
3    Pass     High
4    Pass      Low
```

Comment: Yours work just that both ascending is True to achieve the output mentioned above. Thanks lad. U the best

Answer (score 0):

You need to just `sort` your data by the `Outcome` column, then by the edited `Severity` column. Use:

```
df.sort_values(['Outcome', 'Severity'], key= lambda x: x.replace('Low', 2).replace('Medium', 1).replace('High', 0))
```